# wordpress - Show subcategories only for selected category page

Tags: wordpress

my category and subcategories sample is:

```
+ car
 - bmw
 - audi
 - Mercedes-Benz
```

This is my code.
But this code will not work in multiple categories. I want to show I selected subcategories

---

```
<?php
      $categories = get_the_category();
      if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[1]->term_id ) ) . '" class="value">' . esc_html( $categories[1]->name ) . '</a>';
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

You should be able use [get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) to do this. If you pass the 'child_of' argument, you should be able to get all categories that are children of another category.

```
<?php 

$category = get_the_category();
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'child_of' => $category[1]->term_id // id of the category you want the subcategories of
));

foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ) . '" class="value">' . esc_html( $cat->name ) . '</a>';
}

?>
```

**Original**

You'll need to loop through `$categories` and echo out the information for each category. Should look something like this:

```
<?php 

$category = get_the_category();
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'child_of' => $category[1]->term_id 
));

foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ) . '" class="value">' . esc_html( $cat->name ) . '</a>';
}

?>
```

Comment: This code displays all the selected category. I just want to show subdirectories of a selected category. The category's ID and name display subcategories. TNX

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I updated my answer with another take on this that should work.